# How can I run sqlcmd.exe using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have something that I can run using cmd.exe but now want to do this in PowerShell. How can I rewrite this to work in PowerShell?

```
#username of db
set username=user
set pwd= password1
#server IP or server name 
set server=test/database1
#database name you are logging into
set dbname=database1
#sql file name
set sqlScript=C:\Scripts\testTables.sql

sqlcmd.exe  -S%server% -U%username% -P%pwd%   -d%dbname% -o"tables.lis"  -i %sqlScript%
```

Comment: Learning how to use [variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables) would the place to start.

Comment: Whats this got to do with bash?

Comment: PowerShell does not use `%variablename%` syntax but rather `$env:variablename`.

Comment: Your syntax does not looks like PowerShell syntax.

Comment: You would write some PowerShell. Take it bit by bit. Figure out how to do one line in PowerShell, then the next, etc. If you know what the batch file is doing you shouldn't have any problems translating it to PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this snippet:

```
# Path to your sqlcmd.exe
$app = 'sqlcmd.exe'

# Execute the exe with the arguments
& $app -s "DBServerName" -u "YourUsername" -p "YourPassword" -d "DatabaseName" -o "OutputFile" -i "Path to your sql script"
```